# Object oriented programming in Graph databases

Tags: database, oop, functional-programming, neo4j, graph-databases

Graph databases store data as nodes, properties and relations. If I need to retrieve some specific data from an object based upon a query, then I would need to retrieve multiple objects (as the query might have a lot of results).

Consider this simple scenario in object oriented programming in graph-databases:

I have a (graph) database of users, where each user is stored as an object. I need to retrieve a list of users living in a specific place (the place property is stored in the user object). So, how would I do it? I mean unnecessary data will be retrieved every time I need to do something (in this case, the entire user object might need to be retrieved). Isn't functional programming better in graph databases?

This example is just a simple analogy of the above stated question that came to my mind. Don't take it as a benchmark. So, the question remains, **How great is object oriented programming in graph-databases?**

Comment: I'd rather make the places nodes and connect users to them using relationships. - Why use a graphdb just like you'd some non-graphy kind of storage?! AFAIK all graph databases come with indexing support, so you'd use that instead of inspecting the property values one by one. - I think you're mixing up two different concerns: using OO programming doesn't mean you have to load full objects from the DB at all times. Maybe you could try to make the question more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each node has attributes that can be mapped to object fields. You can do that manually, or you can use [spring-data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data) to do the mapping.

Answer (score 3):

A graph database is more than just vertices and edges. In most graph databases, such as neo4j, in addition to vertices having an `id` and edges having a `label` they have a list of properties. Typically in java based graph databases these properties are limited to java primatives -- everything else needs to be serialized to a string (e.g. dates). This mapping to vertex/edge properties can either be done by hand using methods such as `getProperty` and `setProperty` or you can something like [Frames](https://github.com/tinkerpop/frames), an object mapper that uses the [TinkerPop](http://www.tinkerpop.com/) stack.

Answer (score 1):

Most graph databases have at least one kind of index for vertices/edges. InfiniteGraph, for instance, supports B-Trees, Lucene (for text) and a distributed, scaleable index type. If you don't have an index on the field that you're trying to use as a filter you'd need to traverse the graph and apply predicates yourself at each step. Hopefully, that would reduce the number of nodes to be traversed.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote I need to retrieve a list of users living in a specific place (the place property is stored in the user object).

There is a better way. Separate location from user. Instead of having a location as a property, create a node for locations.
So you can have `(u:User)-[:LIVES_IN]->(l:Location)` type of relationship.

it becomes easier to retrieve a list of users living in a specific place with a simple query:

```
match(u:User)-[:LIVES_IN]->(l:Location) where l.name = 'New York'.
return u,l.
```

This will return all users living in New York without having to scan all the properties of each node. It's a faster approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an object-oriented graph database?

InfiniteGraph is a graph database built on top of Objectivity/DB which is an massively scalable, distributed object-oriented database.

InfiniteGraph allows you to define your vertices and edges using a standard object-oriented approach, including inheritance. You can also embed a defined data type as an attribute in another data type definition.

Because InfiniteGraph is object-oriented, it give you access to query capabilities on complex data structures that are not available in the popular graph databases. Consider the following diagram:

[image]

In this diagram I create a query that determines the inclusion of the edge based on an evaluation of the set of CallDetail nodes hanging off the Call edge. I might only include the edge in my results if there exists a CallDetail with a particular date or if the sum of the callDurations of all of the CallDetails that occurred between two dates is over from threshold. This is the real power of object-oriented database in solving graph problems: You can support a much more complex data model.

I'm not sure why people have comingled the terms graph database and property graph. A property graph is but one way to implement a graph database, and not particular efficient. InfiniteGraph is a schema-based database and the schema provides several distinct advantages, one of which object placement.

Disclaimer: I am the Director of Field Operation for Objectivity, Inc., maker of InfiniteGraph.